# Import OSM Notes dump into PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

I'm planning to write some software to improve handling of OSM Notes, so I need them in postgis database.

Following the [documentation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Notes) I found there is [notes dump on osm.org](http://planet.openstreetmap.org/notes/), but I can't find if there is some software to import this file into database...

Is there other option than writing my own parser?

Comment: Did you considered to use the Dev server instead? AFIAK Rails Port setup is quiet complex... http://dev.osm.org

Comment: @Mapper Maybe this is simplest way, but I'm not familiar with RoR... I'm trying to do something the way I know. All I need for start is simple report where I can search by comment, date or position - this I can do in postgis so I don't need any sophisticated tools. wouldn't it be like shooting a fly with a cannon ?

Comment: Thats the point. I would suggest to surround this problem by testing this clone of the live API. You might also ask over at http://help.osm.org as there is place for support by the OSM community itself :-)